# How to get output of code according to example?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following problem, described below. How could I get output as it is needed in exercise?

Your goal is to complete a function `output = matrix_manip(A, B)`, where A and B are input matrices (represented by np.array). The `matrix_manip` function should return a python dict containing the results of the operations described below. 
To have some data to work with, lets use the following matrix A:

```
A = np.array([[16,  2,  3, 13],
              [ 5, 11, 10,  8],
              [ 9,  7,  6, 12],
              [ 4, 14, 15,  1]])
```

Find the transpose of the matrix A and return it in `output['A_transpose']`. Example result:

```
>>> output['A_transpose']
array([[16,  5,  9,  4],
       [ 2, 11,  7, 14],
       [ 3, 10,  6, 15],
       [13,  8, 12,  1]])
```

I have no problems with using numpy functions. I tried to do it using following construction:

```
def A_transpose(A):
    return np.transpose(A)
```

but that solves correctly, but, of course, does not work with 
`output['A_transpose']`. How could I reach needed result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're asking how to use a dict, no?

You just need to create the dict, put in the required values, then return it.

```
def matrix_manip(A, B):
    results = {}
    results['A_transpose'] = np.transpose(A)
    # ... More code here ...
    return results

output = matrix_manip(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[16, 2, 3, 13],
[ 5, 11, 10, 8],
[ 9, 7, 6, 12],
[ 4, 14, 15, 1]])


def A_transpose(A):
    return np.transpose(A)

output = dict()
output['A_transpose'] = A_transpose(A)

>>> output['A_transpose']
array([[16,  5,  9,  4],
       [ 2, 11,  7, 14],
       [ 3, 10,  6, 15],
       [13,  8, 12,  1]])
```